# Count the nodes that have a specific attribute value using xpath?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following in my XML file:

```
<Plan PlanId="3" TierId="11" TierMultiplier="60.61" RoundDown="50"/>
<Plan PlanId="3" TierId="12" TierMultiplier="71.52" RoundDown="100"/>
<Plan PlanId="3" TierId="13" TierMultiplier="92.61" RoundDown="100"/>
<Plan PlanId="3" TierId="14" TierMultiplier="112.84" RoundDown="100"/>
<Plan PlanId="3" TierId="15" TierMultiplier="143.30" RoundDown="100"/>
```

Using javascript I am trying to get a COUNT of the Plan elements that have a PlanId="3".  Here is what I did and I'm getting a count of 1 when it should be 5:

```
var plan3NodeCount = count("/UnderwritingRequest/Plan/@PlanId='3'");

Result: plan3NodeCount: 1
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xpath to select `<Plan>` elements having `PlanId` attribute equals `3` is as follow :

```
/UnderwritingRequest/Plan[@PlanId='3']
```

so I would suggest to try something like this -assuming that `count` is a function that properly executes the xpath parameter and counts number of elements returned- :

```
var plan3NodeCount = count("/UnderwritingRequest/Plan[@PlanId='3']");
```

Comment: har07, that got it.  Thanks so much.  I appreciate your help.